# JavaScript print and AJAX save/delete from database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have created this page to get data from the database, with links to print the shown data and delete it afterwards.

One of the problems is that the JavaScript print function `window.print();` wont work.

Another problem is that after printing the page, I would like to update the database, so people can see that it has been printed before.

Alternatively, the function could also print the page and then immediately deletes data, so people won't need to see if it has been printed before or not.

This is the code for getting the data from the database:

```
<html>
<header>
<script>
function print_table(id)
{
   //print your document
   window.print();
   //send your data
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/Stage/printed_table.php" + id;
   xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</header>
<body>

<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "depits";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Query the database
$resultSet = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM orders");

// Count the returned rows
if($resultSet->num_rows != 0){
// Turn the results into an Array
 while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
 {
   $id = $rows['id'];
   $naam = $rows['naam'];   
   $achternaam = $rows['achternaam'];
   $email = $rows['email'];
   $telefoon = $rows['telefoon'];   
   $bestelling = $rows['bestelling'];   

   echo "<p>Name: $naam $achternaam<br />Email: $email<br />Telefoon: $telefoon<br /> Bestelling: $bestelling<br /> <a href='delete.php?del=$id'>Delete</a> <input type='button' onclick='print_table($id)' value='Print Table' /> </p>";
 }
// Display the results 
}else{
   echo "Geen bestellingen";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and these are the pages for the two server-side functions:

**delete.php**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "depits";

        // Get ID
        $id = $_GET['del'];
        $sql= "DELETE FROM orders WHERE id=" . $id . "";
        // Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Query the database
        $resultSet = $conn->query($sql) or die("Failed".mysql_error());
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Stage%201/bestellingen.php'>";

?>
```

**print_table.php**

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "depits";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Query the database
$id = $_GET['id'];
$resultSet = $conn->query("UPDATE `orders` SET `printed` = 1  WHERE `id` = `$id`");
?>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Please provide the details of what you have tried in order to debug this.

Comment: Please excuse my lack of writing, i was in a hurry here so i just typed without looking back.

Comment: Writing a proper question is going to get you faster (and better) answers than a half-finished question is. Even if the "half-finished" question takes less time to write.

Comment: So the problem for me here is that i am working an entire week on this piece of code (dont laugh, i am a beginner and a student) but i simply cant get to work. The print button simply doesnt work

Comment: in your javascript, where you are making an `AJAX` call, you have to bind your `query string` properly. try this: `xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/Stage/printed_table.php?id=" + id;`

Comment: I was actually hoping that you guys might find a solution considering i lack the neccesary knowledge to do so :(

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers_

Comment: So... i did something that is against the rules? excuse me. It was never my intention to do so.

Comment: It's not against the rules as such, but you are very unlikely to get a answer that will solve your issue when you don't provide a minimal issue description / debug info, just posting code and hoping for some one to solve it rarely brings any answers.

Comment: Ah you are right. It seems you cleaned my mess up abit, thanks for that. However the alternative piece of code, was actually a suggestion. It isnt in the actual code.

Comment: Your console is yelling for syntax errors... Just open it (F12)

Comment: Lastly you have no way of telling if the user allows the print dialogue

Answer (score 1):

You should really check your browser console (F12) to see if there are any JavaScript errors.

One really glaring error I could spot is this line, where the brackets aren't closed. These type of errors could be easily fixed just by checking the console first.

Another error is the variable in the string, it should be sent as a `?key=value` pair.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/Stage/printed_table.php" + id;
```

should be:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/Stage/printed_table.php?id=" + id, true);
```

Another problem would be the URL the above line is calling. I notice you mentioned that your PHP file name is called **print_table.php** instead of **printed_table.php**.